# Discord.js embed image not working. (Could not interpret "{'url': 'https://cdn.nekos.life/boobs/boobs105.gif'}" as string.)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

**My command.js**

*based on some other bots like HarutoHiroki Bot thst open source on Github and the Nekos.life documentation*

```
    const Discord = require('discord.js');
    const client = require('nekos.life');
    const neko = new client();
    
    module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
      if (message.channel.nsfw === true) {
          link = await neko.nsfw.boobs()
          console.log(link)
          const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
              .setAuthor(`Some neko boobs`)
              .setColor('#00FFF3')
              .setImage(link)
              .setFooter(`Bot by`);
              message.channel.send(embed);
        } 
      else {
        message.channel.send("This isn't NSFW channel!")
      }
    };
    
    module.exports.config = {
        name: "boobs",
        description: "",
        usage: "*boobs",
        accessableby: "Members",
        aliases: []
    }
```

**Error:**

```
    > node .
    (node:25052) ExperimentalWarning: Conditional exports is an experimental feature. This feature could change at any time
    Logged in and connected as Bot#1234
    { url: 'https://cdn.nekos.life/boobs/boobs105.gif' }
    (node:25052) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
    embed.image.url: Could not interpret "{'url': 'https://cdn.nekos.life/boobs/boobs105.gif'}" as string.
        at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:170:25)
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    (node:25052) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)(node:25052) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

**My Question**

how to fix this? *(I tried the hole day but didn't got it working need help soon as possible)*

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = require('nekos.life');
const neko = new client();

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
  if (message.channel.nsfw === true) {
      link = await neko.nsfw.boobs()
      const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setAuthor(`Some neko boobs`)
          .setColor('#00FFF3')
          .setImage(link.url)
          .setFooter(`Bot by`);
          message.channel.send(embed);
    } 
  else {
    message.channel.send("This isn't NSFW channel!")
  }
};

module.exports.config = {
    name: "boobs",
    description: "",
    usage: "*boobs",
    accessableby: "Members",
    aliases: []
}
```

Comment: Please always put a bit of explanation in to your answers, so everyone can understand what exactly you changed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `neko.nsfw.boobs()` returns an [`object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object), not a `string`. Try this instead:

```js
const { url } = await neko.nsfw.boobs(); // get only the URL, not the whole object
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
 .setAuthor(`Some neko boobs`)
 .setColor('#00FFF3')
 .setImage(link.url)
 .setFooter(`Bot by`);
message.channel.send(embed);
```

---

Here's a code snippet example:

```js
const link = {
  url: 'https://cdn.nekos.life/boobs/boobs105.gif'
};

console.log(link); // this will not give the link. it will give the whole object

/* using object destructuring, you can use brackets to capture one 
   property of an array. in this case, the url.
   
   Object Destructuring - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment
*/
const {
  url
} = link;

console.log(url); // this will give *only* the link
console.log(link.url); // another method to give only the link
```